Error in Spring Cloud GatewayFilter, on token renewal, using refresh token that gets revoked after single use
I have an API Gateway which uses Spring Cloud Gateway in authorization code flow.
The oAuth server provides refresh and access token on login, but the refresh token can be used only once to get a new access token and a new refresh token on expiry, and after that the previous refresh token is revoked.
This is working well when the web client sends requests at a normal pace. However, we seem to have encountered a race condition when access token has expired and multiple async calls happen. If two or more requests are made from the browser simultaneously, request 1 triggers a refresh with the authorization server. Before request 1 completes, request 2 reaches the gateway and triggers another refresh. The first request will succeed, but the second one will fail because the refresh token has been revoked.
Is there any configuration that can address this issue, or can I make any changes in the filter? Below is my filter, and it gets the error in the authorizeClient method.

Note: I can't make changes in the sso server as that's company policy to revoke refresh token after it's used.


I am using spring-boot v3.3.3 and spring-cloud-gateway v4.1.5

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ClientAuthorizationException;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizeRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebSession;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import com.abc.service.UserService;
import java.time.Duration;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<Object> {
    private final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;
    
    private final UserService userService;

    public CustomTokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory(final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository,
                                                final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                final UserService userService) {
        super(Object.class);
        userService = userService;
        authorizedClientManager = generateDefaultAuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                authorizedClientRepository);
    }

    private ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager generateDefaultAuthorizedClientManager(
            final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        final Duration tokenClockSkewDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(5);
        final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider
                = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().authorizationCode()
                .refreshToken(configurer -> configurer.clockSkew(tokenClockSkewDuration))
                .clientCredentials(configurer -> configurer.clockSkew(tokenClockSkewDuration))
                .password(configurer -> configurer.clockSkew(tokenClockSkewDuration)).build();
        final DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager defaultAuthorizedClientManager
                = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository,
                authorizedClientRepository);
        defaultAuthorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return defaultAuthorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(final Object config) {
        return (exchange, chain) ->
                exchange.getSession().flatMap(mapSession ->
                        exchange.getPrincipal().log("token-relay-filter")
                                .filter(principal -> principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken)
                                .cast(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)
                                .flatMap(this::authorizeClient)
                                .map(auth2AuthenticationToken -> auth2AuthenticationToken.getName())
                                .flatMap(userService::getRoles)
                                .flatMap(userRoles -> this.withBearerAuth(exchange, userRoles))
                                .onErrorResume(ClientAuthorizationException.class,
                                        e -> Mono.defer(() -> exchange.getSession()
                                                .map(WebSession::invalidate))
                                                .map(a -> exchange))
                                .defaultIfEmpty(exchange)
                                .flatMap(chain::filter)

                );
    }

    Mono<ServerWebExchange> withBearerAuth(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final UserRoles userRoles) {
        // add custom jwt token in auth header
    }

    Mono<OAuth2AuthenticationToken> authorizeClient(final OAuth2AuthenticationToken oAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
        final String clientRegistrationId = oAuth2AuthenticationToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();

        return Mono.defer(() -> authorizedClientManager.authorize(
                        createOAuth2AuthorizeRequest(clientRegistrationId, oAuth2AuthenticationToken)))
                .map(oAuth2AuthorizedClient -> oAuth2AuthenticationToken);
    }
    
    private OAuth2AuthorizeRequest createOAuth2AuthorizeRequest(final String clientRegistrationId,
                                                                final Authentication principal) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId).principal(principal).build();
    }
}

